# Using project class as a database tables synchronously

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mapping

The thing that drive me crazy is, using my project classes as database tables, namely implementing mapping. Here is the details:

Here is my *Product* table:

```
    public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

here is the PRODUCTS table in my database :

```
PRODUCTS
--------------------
PRODUCT_ID
PRODUCT_NAME
PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION
PRODUCT_PRICE
PRODUCT_CATEGORY
```

Here is my DbContext class:

```
    public partial class ProductContext : DbContext
{

    public ProductContext()
        : base("Name=ProductContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<PRODUCTS> Product { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClassAllMap());
    }
}
```

And here is my mapper class:

```
        public ClassAllMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ProductID);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Product");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("PRODUCT_NAME");
        this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION");
        this.Property(t => t.Price).HasColumnName("PRODUCT_PRICE");
        this.Property(t => t.Category).HasColumnName("PRODUCT_CATEGORY");

    }
```

Here is my controller class:

```
    public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private Entities3 repository;

    public ProductController(Entities3 productRepository)
    {
        this.repository = productRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        List<Product> listProduct = new List<Product>();
        using (var db = new ProductContext())
        {

            var products = db.Product.ToList();

            return View(products);
        }

    }

}
```

The problem is that, in the controller class, (or anywhere in the project) I want to use Product List rather than ProductContext.How, which point that I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not get your actual problem... The code above should work or do I miss something

Comment: The problem is that, List<Product> listProduct = new List<Product>(); is empty. I want to use List<Product> listProduct , not var products = db.Product.ToList();

Comment: You clearly have two `Product` classes. You have to convert the EF type to the type in the list, for instance by using AutoMapper.

Comment: In the code , I have only one Product class, demonstrated as public class Product. There is a PRODUCT table in the database. I suppose I have implemented the conversion through public ClassAllMap()  class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to the following

```
public ViewResult List()
{
    List<Product> listProduct; 
    using (var db = new ProductContext())
    {
        listProduct = db.Product.ToList();
        return View(listProduct);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SportsStore.Domain.PRODUCTS>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product>'

Comment: In your DbContext, you can refer to the Product class directly instead of using a (probably) reverse engineered PRODUCT class: `public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }`

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code                                   Additional information: The entity type Product is not part of the model for the current context. What the hell is making simple application.

Comment: hmmm... From the extract I do not see any problem, you may need to adjust the mapping as well.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Although it didn't solve , I mark your answer as a answer.